# Retrieve string from vector

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I stuck in how to retrieve string from vector. My code as following.

in my `.h` file:

```
vector<string>cloudsImages;
```

in my `.m` file:

```
cloudsImages = FileOperation::readFile();

for (int i = 0; i < cloudsImages.size(); i++) {

    cocos2d:: CCSprite *cloudImage = CCSprite::spriteWithSpriteFrame(CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(cloudsImages[i]));
    cloudImage -> setTag(1);
    CCSize winSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
    cloudImage->setPosition(ccp(i,winSize.height / 2));
    this -> addChild(cloudImage);

}
```

When trying to access a string from the vector I get the following error:

> No viable conversion from `std::basic_string<char>` to `const char *`

[image]

How can I retrieve a string from this vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line,

`cocos2d:: CCSprite *cloudImage = CCSprite::spriteWithSpriteFrame(CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(cloudsImages[i]));`

Instead of `cloudsImages[i]`, use `cloudsImages[i].c_str()`. It expects a const char*, which is what the .c_str() returns.

So your line becomes

`cocos2d:: CCSprite *cloudImage = CCSprite::spriteWithSpriteFrame(CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(`**cloudsImages[i].c_str()**`));`

A string in C++ is slightly different from a C-style string. In C, a string is just an array of characters, terminated by the null character '\0'. E.g the string "Hello" in represented by an array of `char`' of length 6 (1 `char` for each character, and 1 for the '\0').

In C++, the `string` class is a wrapper around this basic array. The wrapper allows you to perform operations on the string (e.g. comparing two strings, replacing one string by another, etc). The class **contains** a C-style string, which is used just to hold the characters.

Your function expects a C-style string. To get it from the C++ string, you use the c_str() function, which is a member of the string class.

Comment: Good answer! It could be improved by also explaining what is the difference between a `std::basic_string<char>` and a `const char *`.

Comment: @maditya, how i append .png text to cloudsImages[i].c_str() string?

Comment: You can get the original string, then use `+` to add things to it. For example,

`std::string name = cloudsImages[i] + ".png"; CCSprite::spriteWithSpriteFrame(CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(name.c_str());`